# svn: E175002: connection refused by the server

Tags: svn, teamcity

We're looking into moving our source control from SourceSafe (yes, seriously) to TeamForge and I'm trying to connect TeamCity to TeamForge (collab.net) but *Test Connection* is failing with:

> Error connecting the specified URL:
>
> svn: E175002: connection refused by the server
>
> svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/'

I've been googling on and off for the last few days and tried various things such as `-Dsvnkit.http.sslProtocols=SSLv3` and `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` 
and today updated to TeamCity v9.1.5 (Java version: 1.8.0_66) but still fall at the first hurdle.

For info, TeamCity is behind a corporate proxy server where both TeamCity services run as a domain user that can get through the proxy (got this working for NuGet restore).

Any suggestions as to how I can get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered that svnkit uses its own proxy settings: [proxy settings for subversion](http://svnkit.com/kb/user-guide-config-settings.html)

> By default SVNKit uses proxy settings from the servers configuration file that is located in the default SVN run-time configuration area.
>
> Default configuration area is located at ~/.subversion on Linux and OS X and at C:\Documents and Settings\userName\Application Data\Subversion on Windows.

When creating a VCS Root to Subversion, TeamCity offers a couple of settings under *SVN Connection Settings*, a checkbox *Default config directory* and a text box *Configuration directory*.

I unchecked the default directory and pointed the *Configuration Directory* to the directory created as described below.

- Create a folder within TeamCity: ***C:\TeamCity\conf\Subversion***
- Create a file in this folder named ***servers*** (no extension) with the following content:

```bash
http-proxy-host = proxy.example.com
http-proxy-port = 80
```